# dynamically assign values to IList<T> using generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to set the property of the class member dynamically using reflection

Here is my class and I am trying to set the list dynamically i.e. `ResponseBody`

```
public class Response<T>  where T : RealmObject
{
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

    public string totalPages {get;set;}


    public IList<T> ResponseBody { get; set; }
}
```

following is the response from server that I am trying to map it in `ResponseBody`

```
{
  "errorMessage": "",
  "status": "Ok",
  "totalPages": 1,
  "contactsList": [
    {
      "firstName": "Ronald",
      "lastName": "Brownn"
    },
    {

      "firstName": "Elvis",
      "lastName": "Presley"
    }
  ]
}
```

in order to change map the `contactsList` to `ResponseBody` inside the `JsonConverter` I have writting following code

Following code will create `Response<Contact>` dynamically, consider `entityType` as `Contact`

```
var responseObj = typeof(Response<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { entityType });
var response = Activator.CreateInstance(responseObj);
```

Following code will dynamically create object `IList<Contact>`

```
var responseDataList = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { entityType });
var responseList = Activator.CreateInstance(responseDataList);
var responseEntityList =  jArray.ToObject(responseDataList);
```

now I want to assign `IList<Contact>` to `Response<Contact>`'s `ResponseBody` member and I really don't know how to do that

Comment: I don't understand why `JsonConvert.DeserialiseObject(string, type)` isn't enough?  Could you pass the reflected type into that method as parameter?  Newtonsoft will deserialise lists just fine, normally.  I think all this reflection is confusing matters - maybe I'm missing why you're using it, but if you have a reference to the correct type, which you must have cus you're using reflection, you can just use that in newtonsoft's methods...  JUST realised why you're using reflection. OK OK.  lol.

Comment: @DanRayson i will give it a try though :) but at the same time can you provide some snippet code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a PropertyInfo object from the class definition:

```
var responseBodyProperty = responseObj.getProperty("ResponseBody");
```

then you can use this to set the value on your object:

```
responseBodyProperty.setValue(response, responseList);
```

I don't think it matters at this point that there are generics involved. You've already covered that in your type creation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that reflection is needed here - Deserialisation should be able to handle lists just fine.

I also found why you're probably not seeing the results you expected;  You have `contactsList` in your JSON, but `ResponseBody` in your C# POCO.  That'll be why!

Here's a working version:

**Response Class**

```
public class Response<T> where T : class
{
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

    public string totalPages { get; set; }


    public IList<T> ResponseBody { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON used**

```
{
    "errorMessage": "",
    "status": "Ok",
    "totalPages": 1,
    "ResponseBody": [  <-- notice I changed this
        {
            "firstName": "Ronald",
            "lastName": "Brownn"
        },
        {

            "firstName": "Elvis",
            "lastName": "Presley"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Actual code:**

```
class Program
{
    //Here I'm loading in your json for testing.
    static string input = File.ReadAllText("Input.json");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type genericResponseType = typeof(Response<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { typeof(Person) });
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input, genericResponseType);

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Person class:**

```
public class Person
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i dont have control over the JSON returned from the server so i have to manually map the list

Comment: Understood.  I think if you're getting a dynamic (many possible types) list, and your method already gets the correct type for your message, then you could just deserialise the `Response<>` part first, then deserialise the list<T> separately, then set that value on the response object.  You could strip out the array from the JSON with a little string searching magic for your list.  The fact that the list is strongly-typed and you don't have the type available in code for when you set it, well, in that case I think that @Rup has the perfect answer!

Comment: Thanks for the efforts though